# ¿Por qué no funciona mi rompecabezas?

Tags: javascript, html

He creado un rompecabezas partiendo de uno con 25 piezas, hay una libre para poder mover el resto y conseguir una fotografía. 
El problema es que le modifiqué para usar 16 piezas y no funciona.
Muestro el código, y los cambios que hice los hago con comentarios para anular ese código, si se quitan funciona con 25 piezas.

```js
// crear una matriz de diapositivas
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var blank = slide[Math.sqrt(slide.length) - 1];//para identificar la diapositiva en blanco
var root = Math.sqrt(slide.length);
for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    slide[i].frameNumber = i + 1;
    slide[i].coOrdinate = i + 1;// esto cambia con la posición de la diapositiva. ¡nunca es constante!
}

var slideTraced = function (number) {
    for (var a = 0; a < slide.length; a++) {
        if (slide[a].coOrdinate == number) {
            return slide[a];
        }
    }
};

 // esta función dispersa las diapositivas aleatoriamente cuando la ventana se carga .....
var randomization = function () {
    var movementOrder = [1, root, -1, -root];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        var guestPosition = blank.coOrdinate + (movementOrder[Math.floor(Math.random() * movementOrder.length)]);
        if (guestPosition > 0 && guestPosition <= slide.length) {
            var guest = slideTraced(guestPosition);
            var left = blank.coOrdinate;
            var right = guest.coOrdinate;
            if (left % root == 0 && right % root == 1) {
                i--;
            } else if (left % root == 1 && right % root == 0) {
                i--;
            } else {
                var swPos = guest.getAttribute("style");
                var swPosBl = blank.getAttribute("style");
                guest.coOrdinate = left;
                blank.coOrdinate = right;
                guest.setAttribute("style", swPosBl);
                blank.setAttribute("style", swPos);
            }
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    }
};


  // llama a la función de aleatorización en la ventana de carga y dispersa las diapositivas ..
window.addEventListener("load", randomization);

// esta es una función para cambiar las posiciones de diapositivas en el clic del usuario ....
var changePosition = function () {
    var left = this.coOrdinate;
    var right = blank.coOrdinate;
    var possibility = left - right;
    if (possibility == 1 || possibility == -1 || possibility == root || possibility == -root) {
        if (left % root == 1 && right % root == 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (left % root == 0 && right % root == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var swapped = this.coOrdinate;
            var swPos = this.getAttribute("style");
            var swPosBl = blank.getAttribute("style");
            this.coOrdinate = blank.coOrdinate;
            blank.coOrdinate = swapped;
            this.setAttribute("style", swPosBl);
            blank.setAttribute("style", swPos);
        }
    }
};

// aplica la función changePosition en todas las diapositivas ...
for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    slide[i].addEventListener("click", changePosition);
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .main {
    margin:10px auto;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }
  
  body {
      background: grey;
  }
  
  h1, p {
    font-family:open sans;
    margin:5px auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 95%;
  }
  
  .board {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    padding-bottom: 90%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index:0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px black inset;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
  
  
  .box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 25%;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-image: url("http://i2.esmas.com/2015/10/09/808630/bob-esponja-y-mad-men...-juntos-330x330.jpg");
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px black;
    background-size: 500%;
  }
  
  .border {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  div.one {
    background-position: 0% 0%;  
  }
  
  div.two {
    background-position: -100% 0%;  
  }
  
  div.three {
    background-position: -200% 0%;  
  }
  
  div.four {
    background-position: -300% 0%;  
  }
  
  div.five {
    background: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px black;  
  }
  
  .five .border {
      border: none;
  }
  
  div.six {
    background-position: 0% -100%;  
  }
  
  div.seven {
    background-position: -100% -100%;  
  }
  
  div.eight {
    background-position: -200% -100%;  
  }
  
  div.nine {
    background-position: -300% -100%;  
  }
  
  div.ten {
    background-position: -400% -100%;  
  }
  
  div.eleven {
    background-position: 0% -200%;  
  }
  
  div.twelve {
    background-position: -100% -200%;  
  }
  
  div.thirteen {
    background-position: -200% -200%;  
  }
  
  div.fourteen {
    background-position: -300% -200%;  
  }
  
  div.fifteen {
    background-position: -400% -200%;  
  }
  
  div.sixteen {
    background-position: 0% -300%;  
  }
  
  /*div.seventeen {
    background-position: -100% -300%;  
  }
  
  div.eighteen {
    background-position: -200% -300%;  
  }
  
  div.nineteen {
    background-position: -300% -300%;  
  }
  
  div.twenty {
    background-position: -400% -300%;  
  }
  
  div.twenty_one {
    background-position: 0% -400%;  
  }
  
  div.twenty_two {
    background-position: -100% -400%;  
  }
  
  div.twenty_three {
    background-position: -200% -400%;  
  }
  
  div.twenty_four {
    background-position: -300% -400%;  
  }
  
  div.twenty_five {
    background-position: -400% -400%;  
  }
  
  #music{
    display: none; 
    autoplay: true;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>

<head>
    <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Rompecabezas</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Puzzle</h1>
    <p>Haz clic en las piezas para hacer la foto</p>

    <div class="main">

        <div class="board" id="board">

            <div class="box one" style="top:0%;left:0%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                  
            <div class="box two" style="top:0%;left:25%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>          
            <div class="box three" style="top:0%;left:50%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                  
            <div class="box four" style="top:0%;left:75%;"><div class="border"> </div> </div>                       
            <div class="box five" style="top:25%;left:0%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box six" style="top:25%;left:25%;"><div class="border"> </div> </div>                      
            <div class="box seven" style="top:25%;left:50%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                        
            <div class="box eight" style="top:25%;left:75%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                        
            <div class="box nine" style="top:50%;left:0%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                          
            <div class="box ten" style="top:50%;left:25%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box eleven" style="top:50%;left:50%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                           
            <div class="box twelve" style="top:50%;left:75%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                         
            <div class="box thirteen" style="top:75%;left:0%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                      
            <div class="box fourteen" style="top:75%;left:25%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                       
            <div class="box fifteen" style="top:75%;left:50%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box sixteen" style="top:75%;left:75%;"><div class="border"> </div> </div>                         
            <!--<div class="box seventeen" style="top:60%;left:20%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                          
            <div class="box eighteen" style="top:60%;left:40%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                        
            <div class="box nineteen" style="top:60%;left:60%;"><div class="border"> </div>  </div>
            <div class="box twenty" style="top:60%;left:80%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box twenty_one" style="top:80%;left:0%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box twenty_two" style="top:80%;left:20%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box twenty_three" style="top:80%;left:40%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box twenty_four" style="top:80%;left:60%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box twenty_five" style="top:80%;left:80%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>-->

        </div>
    </div>
   <!-- <iframe src="audio\entredosaguas.mp3" id="music"></iframe>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Si alguien hizo algo parecido y me puede ayudar

Comment: ¡Ala! ¡Qué montón de código! ¿Has pensado que tal vez no te funciona porque es demasiado código?

Comment: Si funciona, solo necesito añadir una funcion en javascript que me diga cuando he completado la imagen y me de la opcion de seguir un camino u otro, pero no se hacerlo. Gracias

Comment: Ufff... parece complicado, creo que Google ofrece un servicio de reconocimiento de imágenes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El problema son los CSS: Están preparados para recortar la imagen en 25 trozos, ignorando el quinto (la esquina superior derecha). Debes modificarlos para que sea el cuarto div el que tenga `background: none`,
además de recolocar el desplazamiento (el *offset*) de la imagen en el fondo de las restantes.

```js
// crear una matriz de diapositivas
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var blank = slide[Math.sqrt(slide.length) - 1];//para identificar la diapositiva en blanco
var root = Math.sqrt(slide.length);
for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    slide[i].frameNumber = i + 1;
    slide[i].coOrdinate = i + 1;// esto cambia con la posición de la diapositiva. ¡nunca es constante!
}

var slideTraced = function (number) {
    for (var a = 0; a < slide.length; a++) {
        if (slide[a].coOrdinate == number) {
            return slide[a];
        }
    }
};

 // esta función dispersa las diapositivas aleatoriamente cuando la ventana se carga .....
var randomization = function () {
    var movementOrder = [1, root, -1, -root];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        var guestPosition = blank.coOrdinate + (movementOrder[Math.floor(Math.random() * movementOrder.length)]);
        if (guestPosition > 0 && guestPosition <= slide.length) {
            var guest = slideTraced(guestPosition);
            var left = blank.coOrdinate;
            var right = guest.coOrdinate;
            if (left % root == 0 && right % root == 1) {
                i--;
            } else if (left % root == 1 && right % root == 0) {
                i--;
            } else {
                var swPos = guest.getAttribute("style");
                var swPosBl = blank.getAttribute("style");
                guest.coOrdinate = left;
                blank.coOrdinate = right;
                guest.setAttribute("style", swPosBl);
                blank.setAttribute("style", swPos);
            }
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    }
};


  // llama a la función de aleatorización en la ventana de carga y dispersa las diapositivas ..
window.addEventListener("load", randomization);

// esta es una función para cambiar las posiciones de diapositivas en el clic del usuario ....
var changePosition = function () {
    var left = this.coOrdinate;
    var right = blank.coOrdinate;
    var possibility = left - right;
    if (possibility == 1 || possibility == -1 || possibility == root || possibility == -root) {
        if (left % root == 1 && right % root == 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (left % root == 0 && right % root == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var swapped = this.coOrdinate;
            var swPos = this.getAttribute("style");
            var swPosBl = blank.getAttribute("style");
            this.coOrdinate = blank.coOrdinate;
            blank.coOrdinate = swapped;
            this.setAttribute("style", swPosBl);
            blank.setAttribute("style", swPos);
        }
    }
};

// aplica la función changePosition en todas las diapositivas ...
for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    slide[i].addEventListener("click", changePosition);
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .main {
    margin:10px auto;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }
  
  body {
      background: grey;
  }
  
  h1, p {
    font-family:open sans;
    margin:5px auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 95%;
  }
  
  .board {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    padding-bottom: 90%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index:0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px black inset;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
  
  
  .box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 25%;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-image: url("http://i2.esmas.com/2015/10/09/808630/bob-esponja-y-mad-men...-juntos-330x330.jpg");
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px black;
    background-size: 400%;
  }
  
  .border {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  div.one {
    background-position: 0% 0%;  
  }
  
  div.two {
    background-position: -100% 0%;  
  }
  
  div.three {
    background-position: -200% 0%;  
  }
  
  div.four {
    background: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px black;
  }
  
  .four .border {
      border: none;
  }
  
  div.five {
    background-position: 0% -100%;    
  }
  
  
  
  div.six {
    background-position: -100% -100%;  
  }
  
  div.seven {
     background-position: -200% -100%;  
  }
  
  div.eight {
    background-position: -300% -100%;  
  }
  
  div.nine {
   background-position: 0% -200%;  
  }
  
  div.ten {
   background-position: -100% -200%;  
  }
  
  div.eleven {
   background-position: -200% -200%;  
  }
  
  div.twelve {
    background-position: -300% -200%;
  }
  
  div.thirteen {
   background-position: 0% -300%;  
  }
  
  div.fourteen {
   background-position: -100% -300%;  
  }
  
  div.fifteen {
   background-position: -200% -300%;  
  }
  
  div.sixteen {
    background-position: -300% -300%;  
  }
```

```html
    <h1>Puzzle</h1>
    <p>Haz clic en las piezas para hacer la foto</p>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="board" id="board">
            <div class="box one" style="top:0%;left:0%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                 <div class="box two" style="top:0%;left:25%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>   
            <div class="box three" style="top:0%;left:50%;"><div class="border"> </div></div> 
            <div class="box four" style="top:0%;left:75%;"><div class="border"> </div> </div> 
            <div class="box five" style="top:25%;left:0%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box six" style="top:25%;left:25%;"><div class="border"> </div> </div> 
            <div class="box seven" style="top:25%;left:50%;"><div class="border"> </div></div> 
            <div class="box eight" style="top:25%;left:75%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                        
            <div class="box nine" style="top:50%;left:0%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                          
            <div class="box ten" style="top:50%;left:25%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box eleven" style="top:50%;left:50%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                           
            <div class="box twelve" style="top:50%;left:75%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                         
            <div class="box thirteen" style="top:75%;left:0%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                      
            <div class="box fourteen" style="top:75%;left:25%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                       
            <div class="box fifteen" style="top:75%;left:50%;"> <div class="border"> </div> </div>
            <div class="box sixteen" style="top:75%;left:75%;"><div class="border"> </div> </div>                         
            

        </div>
    </div>
```

Bonus: cómo funcionan las celdas de tu puzzle:

- Tu puzle ahora es de 4*4, quedémonos con el 4.
- Todas las celdas tienen la clase box, que añade una imagen como fondo, ocupando el (4 * 100)% **de la celda**. Es decir, si la celda tiene un tamaño de N*N pixels, la imagen se extiende hasta ocupar 4N*4N pixels, con lo que sólo se ve una parte (una décimosexta parte, 1/(4*4)).
- Ahora toca elegir qué parte de la imagen muestra cada celda, y eso se consigue moviendo el fondo: si el offset (background-position) es 0, 0, verás la esquina superior izquierda.
- Al añadir un 100% (el tamaño de las celdas) en cualquier dirección (vertical u horizontal), estamos desplazando la imagen 1/4 (porque la imagen tiene un tamaño relativo de 400%). Pero como queremos moverla para la izquierda o hacia arriba, usamos números negativos, con lo que la esquina superior derecha se ve cuando usamos `background-position: -300% 0%;`

Comment: Buenas.Lo de el cuarto div me ha quedado claro, imagina que por ahi andaba la cosa, pero tengo mis dudas de como recolocar el desplazamiento (el offset),¿ como lo debo hacer?                                                        Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Simplemente mira lo que he puesto y aprende qué hace background-position

Comment: Buenas. Perdona que vuelva a molestarte, he estado viendo background-position en varios sitios W3C, MDN, y todavia no entiendo el criterio que debo usar para cambiar el porcentage de background-position. Me puedes aconsejar algun sitio donde pueda estudiar para entender  y poder  cambiar el numero de celdas en diferentes posibilidades....??                                                                                                  Y nuevo, perdona las molestias. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Te he añadido más detalles

Comment: Gracias, ahora lo tengo mas claro. Solo me queda como crear la funcion

Comment: Buenas, he creado un puzzle 9 piezas solo, para provar la funcion que me avise cuando termino ( con 16 tardaba mucho en completarle) y he tratado de hacer lo que me explicaste, pero me salen partes de la imagen repetidas.                                                                                                       Porque puede ser, o que estoy haciendo mal..? Donde puedo buscar solucion a eso..???                                                                                                Gracias, y perdon por las molestias

Comment: ya cree :  function win() {
    var time = min + ":" + sec;
    var win = true;
    for (var i in numbers) {
        if (numbers[i].innerHTML != numbers[i].id) {
            if (numbers[i].id != numbers.length) {
                win = false; break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (win) {
        clearTimer();
        function showAlert() {
            alert("Has ganado...!!! \nUsted hizo" + steps + "movimientos \nTu tiempo a sido " + min + " min. y " + sec + " sec.");
        }
        setTimeout(showAlert, 1000); document.getElementById('9').innerHTML = "9";
    }
}

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Si quieres hablar sobre el juego, podemos hacerlo en el chat, en las preguntas no tiene demasiado sentido ;)